# Problems posting images from react to Django Rest API using redux

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, antd

I'm trying to post an image in my Django API from a react form with no luck. I'm also using the image uploader from AntDesign library and redux.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

-Form Code:

```
class ArticleForm extends React.Component {
     this.props.onSendNewArticle(
     fieldsValue.upload.fileList[0].originFileObj);
     render() {
        <Form.Item
        name="upload"
        label="Image"
        onPreview={this.handlePreview}>
           <Upload accept=".jpeg, .png" beforeUpload={() => false}>
             <Button>
               <UploadOutlined /> Choisir une image
             </Button>
           </Upload>
        </Form.Item>
    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        loading_add_article: state.add_article.loading_add_article,
        error_add_article: state.add_article.error_add_article,
      };
    };
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        onSendNewArticle: (image) =>
          dispatch(actions.articleAdded(image)),
      };
    };
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CourseForm);
```

-Here's my view.py

```
class ArticleCreateView(APIView):
  

parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    article_serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
    
    if article_serializer.is_valid():
        article_serializer.save()
        return Response(article_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        print('error', article_serializer.errors)
        return Response(article_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

-Here's my store/actions/addArticle.js:

```
export const articleAdded = ( image) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(articleDispached);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/create/", {
        img: image
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const course = res.data;
        dispatch(articleAddSucess(course));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(articleAddFailed(err));
      });
  };
};
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/create/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
```

Comment: Did you try adding headers with 'multipart/form-data' as content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const articleAdded = ( image) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(articleDispached);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/create/", {
        img: image
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        const course = res.data;
        dispatch(articleAddSucess(course));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(articleAddFailed(err));
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).